# Can the entities (a,b,c,t1,x,y,z) and (a,b,c,t2,x,y,z) exist both at the same time?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Suppose we have two entity sets, A, with attributes a,b,c and B, with attributes x,y,z, and also a relationship between them C, with attribute t.

It it possible for the entities (a,b,c,t<sub>1</sub>,x,y,z) and (a,b,c,t<sub>2</sub>,x,y,z) to exist at the same time in the ER model?

I think that since "t" is an attribute of the relation between them, it should not count, so it should not be possible. Is this right?